# Migrate development PostgreSQL data to Railway

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've been using PostgreSQL in development and populating the database with some data. I deployed the whole app to Railway following [these steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment#getting_your_website_ready_to_publish).

When I create a new database in the railway production server it will always be a blank database. How can I migrate the data of my development database to Railway production's?

The code I have in my Django's settings.py file is this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'basededatos1',
        'USER': 'db_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'mYWZQy65viXG50wohppK.Z%uauhghs.CuB#k}nE45A=nK}Qe1*_g=sJF~*0}nQ^!aMuCL#]1i+i-hvs1N8:0Q9fGCdC1gNGc5g~T',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And added this code while following the deployment tutorial:

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

The newly created PostgreSQL database in the Railway production dashboard is a blank, new database with different parameters to the one I had, but can't edit them. What is the way to go for using my development database's data into production?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you will need to assign your railway project some environment variables that reference your database credentials. I am also struggling to connect my database to my railway service.
Within your railway console, visit the project you wish to connect, select the variables tab, and then RAW Editor.
Also, I really hope those aren't your actual database credentials.